# django Testing views works only with a primary key

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a django project. i have build the front end and back-end. now i want to write unit test.

i want to test a class based view for creating,deleting and retrieving blog post from url '''path('posts/', Postview.as_view(),name="posts"),'''
my Postview view is here:

```
class Postview(views.APIView, LimitOffsetPagination):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        if pk:
            try:
                query = Post.objects.filter(pk=pk)
                # print(query)
                print("in post get")
                serializer = PostSerializer(
                    query, many=True, context={'request': request})
                data = commonPost(serializer.data, request)
                return Response(data)
            except:
                return Response({"message": "No Data found"})
        else:
            query = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
            serializer = PostSerializer(
                query, many=True, context={'request': request})
            data = commonPost(serializer.data, request)
            return Response(data)

    def post(self, request, pk=None):
        if pk:
            snapshot = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
            serializers = PostSerializer(
                snapshot, data=request.data, context={'request': request})
            if serializers.is_valid():
                serializers.save()
                return Response({'error': False})
            return Response({'error': True})
        else:
            serializer = PostSerializer(
                data=request.data, context={'request': request})
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response({'error': False})
            return Response({'error': True})

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        try:
            snippet = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
            if snippet.profile.id == request.user.profile.id:
                snippet.delete()
                return Response({"error": False})
            else:
                return Response({"error": True})
        except:
            return Response({"message": "No data found for this ID"})
```

now my unit test

```
def test_post_view(self):
        client=self.get_client()
        response=client.get("/api/posts/")# this line
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,200)
```

this test gives error of 401!=200
but if i change the url
to

```
response=client.get("/api/posts/1")
```

the test gives 200_k.
also if i create a new post via `client.post("/api/posts/",self.post) #here the post object created through Post model of my Custom Post class.`
the response returns 401!=200.
i want to know why it is behaving like this and i would like to know how to create unit testing for this piece of code.
Thank YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. So you wrote you have a problem with `POST` method but

```
def test_post_view(self):
        client=self.get_client()
        response=client.get("/api/posts/")# this line
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,200)
```

here you use `GET` method.

2. `POST` doesn't accept any `pk` because it creates a new resource.
   So this is invalid.

```
client.post("/api/posts/",self.post)
```

3. The error is 401 and you use `IsAuthenticated` permission. Create a user in `setUpClass` or `setUp` first and in `setUp` login with this user

```
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.client.force_login(self.user)
```

4. For "not found" you return `Response({"message": "No Data found"})` but it should return status code 404.

I see you're relatively new to these things. Maybe start with `ModelViewSet` first. It will force best practices and probably you will write less code.